# How to create a flag of exclusion for duplicate rows in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Given below is the snapshot of my data

```
NameAgeIncome Group
Asd 20  A
Asd 20  A
b   19  E
c   21  B
c   21  B
c   21  B
df  21  C
rd  24  D
```

I want ot include a flag variable where it says 1 to one of the duplicate row and 0 to another. And also 0 to rest of the rows which are not duplicate. Given below is the snapshot of final desired output

```
NameAgeIncome Group Flag
Asd 20  A   1
Asd 20  A   0
b   19  E   0
c   21  B   1
c   21  B   1
c   21  B   0
df  21  C   0
rd  24  D   0
```

Can anyone help me how to create this Flag variable in Oracle database

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80107/how-to-create-a-flag-of-exclusion-for-duplicate-rows-in-oracle

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using analytic functions and `case`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by name, age, income order by name) = 1
             then 0 else 1
        end) as GroupFlag
from table t;
```